# Does CLR (.NET) allow two applications to execute in the same execution environment?

Tags: .net, clr

I'm  a Java dev that  needs to move to .NET. My question is, does the CLR allow (easily) two or more .NET applications to run side by side on the SAME CLR?

Comment: Probably I misunderstand you question; you simple double-click two different executables or you double-click the same executable twice.

Comment: It would be pretty awful if you couldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here but it seems like one of the following

1. Does the CLR allow the same application to run in 2 separate processes? Yes
2. Does the CLR allow the same application to run in parallel in the same process? Yes (via AppDomains)
3. Does the CLR allow for itself to be hosted several times in the same process? 2.0 and 4.0 can be hosted Side By Side in the same process.

Comment: the thing is, given that I have app A and app B, can I run both with the same CLR?

Comment: @Marcos do you mean the same CLR instance or having the apps run in 2 processes using the same CLR version and install?

Comment: I mean the same CLR instance;
For instance in Java you could have a master process, and instantiate two ClassLoader each one for each application;

Comment: @Marcos yes you can use 2 AppDomains to load them into the same CLR instance

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide me some tutorial or tip? I'm really new on C# and .NET :/, I'm confused with all the terms there

Comment: @Marcos unfortunately they are a bit of a complex part so there is no great succint tutorial out there.  This is the best place to start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9.aspx